# Infinispan 14.0.1 Final cli.sh batch mode does not work anymore

Tags: infinispan

I`m playing around with the new infinispan version 14.0.1 Final but it seems that
since Infinispan 14.0.1 Final cli.sh batch mode does not work anymore.

i have tried the following:

```
echo describe | ${INFINISPAN_HOME}/bin/cli.sh -c http://****:*****@localhost:11222 -f - | grep RUNNING
command terminated with exit code 1
```

without batch mode it works:

```
${INFINISPAN_HOME}/bin/cli.sh -c http://****:*****@localhost:11222
[f314abe638e2-57726@cluster//containers/default]> describe
{
  "version" : "14.0.1.Final",
  "name" : "default",
  "coordinator" : true,
  "cache_configuration_names" : [ "org.infinispan.REPL_ASYNC","___protobuf_metadata","org.infinispan.DIST_SYNC","org.infinispan.LOCAL","org.infinispan.INVALIDATION_SYNC","respCache","org.infinispan.REPL_SYNC","example.PROTOBUF_DIST","org.infinispan.SCATTERED_SYNC","org.infinispan.INVALIDATION_ASYNC","___script_cache","org.infinispan.DIST_ASYNC" ],
  "cluster_name" : "cluster",
  "physical_addresses" : "[10.88.0.35:7800]",
  "coordinator_address" : "f314abe638e2-57726",
  "cache_manager_status" : "RUNNING",
  "created_cache_count" : 1,
  "running_cache_count" : 1,
  "node_address" : "f314abe638e2-57726",
  "cluster_members" : [ "f314abe638e2-57726" ],
  "cluster_members_physical_addresses" : [ "10.88.0.35:7800" ],
  "cluster_size" : 1,
  "defined_caches" : [ {
    "name" : "___script_cache",
    "started" : true
  },{
    "name" : "___protobuf_metadata",
    "started" : true
  },{
    "name" : "respCache",
    "started" : true
  } ],
  "local_site" : null,
  "relay_node" : false,
  "relay_nodes_address" : [  ],
  "sites_view" : [  ],
  "rebalancing_enabled" : true
}
```

with version 13.0.12 it still works:

```
echo describe | ${INFINISPAN_HOME}/bin/cli.sh -c http://****:*****@localhost:11222 -f - | grep RUNNING
"cache_manager_status" : "RUNNING",

bash-4.4$ echo describe | ${INFINISPAN_HOME}/bin/cli.sh -c http://cliuser:changeit@localhost:11222 -f -
{
  "version" : "13.0.12.Final",
  "name" : "default",
  "coordinator" : true,
  "cache_configuration_names" : [ "org.infinispan.REPL_ASYNC","___protobuf_metadata","org.infinispan.DIST_SYNC","org.infinispan.LOCAL","org.infinispan.INVALIDATION_SYNC","org.infinispan.REPL_SYNC","example.PROTOBUF_DIST","org.infinispan.SCATTERED_SYNC","org.infinispan.INVALIDATION_ASYNC","___script_cache","org.infinispan.DIST_ASYNC" ],
  "cluster_name" : "cluster",
  "physical_addresses" : "[10.88.0.36:7800]",
  "coordinator_address" : "437060144b6b-64461",
  "cache_manager_status" : "RUNNING",
  "created_cache_count" : 0,
  "running_cache_count" : 0,
  "node_address" : "437060144b6b-64461",
  "cluster_members" : [ "437060144b6b-64461" ],
  "cluster_members_physical_addresses" : [ "10.88.0.36:7800" ],
  "cluster_size" : 1,
  "defined_caches" : [ {
    "name" : "___protobuf_metadata",
    "started" : true
  },{
    "name" : "___script_cache",
    "started" : true
  } ],
  "local_site" : null,
  "relay_node" : false,
  "relay_nodes_address" : [  ],
  "sites_view" : [  ],
  "rebalancing_enabled" : true
}
```

can someone reproduce that ?

Comment: I've reproduced it and created https://issues.redhat.com/browse/ISPN-14256

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug where the CLI doesn't work with piped input https://issues.redhat.com/browse/ISPN-14256
It will be fixed in Infinispan 14.0.3.Final